# Will the flag on the day of Judgment also be fixed behind the buttocks for the sinners and kaafirs?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation

I came across this hadith and need a explanation for it, from the muhaditheen or any scholars.

> It is narrated on the authority of Abu Sa'id that the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: On the Day of Judgment there will be a flag fixed behind the buttocks of every person guilty of the breach of faith. -- Sahih Muslim 1738 a ([sunnah.com](https://sunnah.com/muslim/32/18))

Will this flag on the day of Judgment be fixed behind the buttocks or inside the sinners and kaafirs?!

Comment: Maybe the next hadith gives you a hint http://sunnah.com/muslim/32/19

Answer (score 1):

The proper translation is:

**There is a flag for each perfidious behind his buttocks at the Day of Resurrection.**

It means defamatory of his treachery and exposes in front of people.
 Behind his buttocks, because the flag of pride stands in front of the face, so it is appropriate to humiliate him by putting the humiliation flag the opposite.
And this is for Muslims too…and that does not include the trick in war.